# Make clients in same machine run on different thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read a client-server application and clients interact together through server. So, for this purpose, I want to create client on different thread. (if not, they often block by IO).

Here is my client code :

```
public class Client {

   //some client code here

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                System.out.println("Client creator thread id: " + threadId);
                                Client c = new Client();
                                // some code to run client
            }

        }.start();
   }
}
```

I run this class file multiply times (by running directly in IDE, or create bat file) . And I notice that all of them are on same thread (same thread id). I cannot explain why.

I think the problem I meet is : I don't create multiply threads in same class, but run this class multiply times. Although I think this makes strange problem, but still cannot explain why.

Please explain for me and how to correct this.

Thanks :)

Comment: you are running many processes with one thread. Rather than one process with many threads

Comment: @OliverWatkins yes I think like you, but I cannot explain. and because of that, cannot fix it.

Comment: why dont you spawn many threads with a for(..) loop? See what happens then and look at the thread ids then.

Comment: @OliverWatkins yes.they will be different. But, I cannot spawn mulithread in client because different client will run again this class.

Comment: then i dont think you can get a different thread ID. The will be different threads (because they are in different processes), but they can have the same ID (because they are in different pocesses, there is no name conflict problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to test / emulate multiple clients, than you should start multiple **processes**. So you also wouldn't have to mess around with creating threads. In reality, the clients will never run in the same process (even not on the same machine?).
That won't make you understand this thing, but I would get you nearer to the reality.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are running a single thread each time, and after it ends you run the `main()` method again, which creates another thread with the same id. The similarity in id is expected as per the documentation in `getID()` method, which says *"When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused."* [Read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29) for more.

Comment: in fact, the client thread is not terminated. server when send data back, multiclients still receive data normally. but clients just meet problem, when they have IO input.

Answer (score 1):

If you spawn the thread in a for loop like this :

```
    public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

             new Thread() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                     System.out.println("Client creator thread id: " + threadId);
                                     Client c = new Client();
                                     // some code to run client
                 }

             }.start();
        }
    }
 }
```

you will find many threads in one process with different IDs. If you just keep running the main(), you are just creating another process with only one thread in it.

Comment: client code is run by different clients, at different time. that the problem I meet :)